# Asp.net validate only one beginform in view that has two foms

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with asp.net mvc 4 razor and i am still new and i have a problem. i already searched the problem and i couldn't find any that i can understand.

Why both of my forms validate when I click the login input type submit?.

How can i make the login validate without affecting the other form and so with register?.

Here's my view:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{ 

   <p >
        ID number:
       @Html.TextBoxFor(e=>e.cID)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.cID)</p>
    <p >
        Password:
       @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.cpassword)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.cpassword)</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login"/></p>

}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{ 

   <p>
        ID number:
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.cID)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.cID)
   </p>
    <p>
        Firstname:
      @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.cfname)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.cfname)
    </p>
    <p>
        Lastname:
       @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.clname)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.clname)
    </p>
    <p>
        Course:
       @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.ccourse,help.GetCourse(), "--Select Course--")
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.ccourse)
    </p>
    <p>
        Password:
       @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.cpassword)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.cpassword)
    </p>
    <p>
        Confirm Password:
       @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.cconfirmpas)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.cconfirmpas)
    </p>
    <p ><input type="submit" value="Register"/></p>
}
```

and my model class:

```
public class Class1
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Id number is mandatory")]
    [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Number Only Please")]
    public int cID { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Firstname is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string cfname { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Lastname is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string clname { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "password is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Use only Alphanumeric")]
    public string cpassword { get; set; }

    public string ccourse { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "confirming a password is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Use only Alphanumeric")]
    [Compare("cpassword", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password doesn't match, Type again !")]
    public string cconfirmpas { get; set; }
}
```

Am I doing it wrong?.

Comment: Why do you have 2 forms in the view - you can only submit one! In any case you need 2 separate models - if you submitted the first form it would be invalid because the model has properties such as `cfname`, `clname` and `cconfirmpas` which are required by you did not submit a value for them.

Comment: okay sir thanks! ill try making two separate models

Comment: And don't include the Register form in the Login form view (have a link to redirect, or load that form using ajax - there is no point generating 3 time as much html when it 99.9% of the time, it's never needed - users only ever register once)